# How to watch an Array for changes in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, observable, es6-proxy

I understand there used to be `Array.observe()` which is now deprecated in favor of Proxies. I read the documentation on proxy traps, but I guess I feel it's pretty brittle for arrays... like let's say I have a array of objects called a shopping cart that I add to using `push` and `splice` and I wanted to watch it for any changes.

```
shopping_cart = []
proxy = new Proxy(shopping_cart, {
  get: function(target, property) {
    if (property == "push") {
      // ...
    } else if (property == "splice") {
      // ...
    }
  }
})
```

This seems brittle to me because there isn't a "catch all" kind of watch and I have to physically write out the methods. But there are many ways to modify an Array, like what if I decide to use `pop` instead or something like that...

Is there a broader trap that the proxy can utilize? Or do I really just have to list out everything...

Comment: If you want to watch for *changes*, why not use the `set` trap? Arrays are not manipulated by calling methods on them, they are manipulated like every other object: by setting their properties.

Comment: You can use RxJS Observable. Will take some time to learn - but its worth it :)

Comment: @Bergi - good luck creating traps for ALL mutating methods of array AND index property accessors (i.e. arr [42] ) without killing the performance.

Comment: @c69 My point was that you do *not* need extra traps for the methods - all they do is mutate indexed properties and `length`. Unlike with getters/setters, you do not need "multiple traps" - just *one* `set` trap.

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean `Set`? How would it look like then? You just got me interested.

Comment: @Kinduser I think he means these [`set` traps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set).

Comment: @Bergi, how would `set` work? My understanding is that `push` and `splice` wouldn't trigger that...

Comment: @james try it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant I have tried it and it doesn't work. Proxies work on Objects and `push` and `splice` are getter methods for the Array object, that's why getter methods work. Granted I could be super stupid and have missed something, so an example would be helpful

Comment: @Bergi Looking forward for your full reply regarding that `set` ((:

Comment: @james ``var p = new Proxy([], { set(target, property, value) { console.log(`Setting ${property} to ${value}`); return Reflect.set(target, property, value); }}); p.push(42);``

Comment: this does work... so dunno i guess i was being reaaaaaallly stupid yesterday. thanks! will delete ethis question shortly since it's kind of invalid

Comment: @Bergi - hmm, that's actually quite an interesting fact ! Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: Don't delete it :) @Bergi Why does it work on `push` while not working on `concat`?

Comment: @Kinduser `concat` doesn’t mutate any array, it just creates a new one.